# LogPlot Fibonaccinumbers from n to m

Tags: plotting

I want to draw the Fibonaccinumbers from 16 -116.

```
Clear[recFib];
recFib[n_] := recFib[n] = recFib[n - 1] + recFib[n - 2]
recFib[0] = 0; recFib[1] = 1;
LogPlot[recFib,{ recFib[], 16,116}]
```

Using this it draws the graph but not the elements without any output of errors.

Comment: try ListLogPlot

Comment: `ListLogPlot[
 RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], a[0] == 1, a[1] == 1}, 
  a, {n, 16, 116}]]`

Comment: @cvgmt this way it presents the numbers in a linear way instead of an exponential one. Any advice how they are presented exponencialy since they are fibonacci numbers they should be exponencialy, right?

Comment: `ListPlot[RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], a[0] == 1, 
   a[1] == 1}, a, {n, 16, 116}], ScalingFunctions -> Automatic]`

Comment: You probably want to use`DiscretePlot[F[n],{n,16,116}]`.